# I got stuck on the onBackPressed() in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am start working on the Asynctask Demo. What I want is , "When I press the back button in the android device I want to stop the task which is running in the app  "

I set up this thing on the onBackPressed() method but after this in the Logcat  Task doesn't stop .

Where am I make  the mistake , help me out of this ?

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new CountDownTask().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    new CountDownTask().cancel(true);
}

private class CountDownTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        TextView tvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);
        tvCounter.setText("START");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int i=15;i>=0;i--){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(i);
                Log.e("Aka", String.valueOf(i));
                if(isCancelled()){
                    break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        TextView tvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);

        tvCounter.setText( Integer.toString(values[0].intValue()));         
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        TextView tvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);
        tvCounter.setText("DONE");          
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Demo works fine . there is  no error in it ..

Comment: It's very simple...change the line `new CountDownTask().execute();` in  your `onCreate(...)` method to be `cT = new CountDownTask().execute();`. Then remove the line `cT = new CountDownTask();` from your `onBackPressed()` method. It is absolutely as simple as that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is in this line

```
new CountDownTask().cancel(true);
```

you are creating a new CountDownTask and canceling it. cancel the existing instance of Asynctask.

For example

```
private CountDownTask cT;  // declare as member
```

start like

```
ct = new CountDownTask();
ct.execute();
```

and cancel like

```
ct.cancel(true);
```

Comment: No idea if/why you got downvoted. This is the correct answer.

Comment: I did the same but still the running task is showing in the LagCat

Comment: There is the counting which I want to stop in the Logcat ... but according to your way , It's still running

Comment: @user2078315 : Read the answer again - StinePike has edited to show `ct.cancel(true)`. It should fix your problem.

Comment: I already done this thing but after the back press  Logcat is still running ..... I have also add the Logcat

Comment: when I pressed the back button I just want to stop the loop in the logcat

Comment: @user2078315, Can you post code after modifications as suggested by StinePike. Suggestion by StinePike is correct. However you may see one extra output in logcat corresponding to first iteration since you are breaking after logging.

Comment: @user2078315, I locally ran the code, and it worked for me. I suggested you to post modified code so that we can point out where you are getting wrong.

Comment: @StinePike : sorry to say , but after this logcat still running .. :(

Comment: @Anirudh.. as far i knew you can not cancel the process in doInBackGround.. check the doc.. write some codes and test.

Comment: sorry for the wrong update .. as it was already implemented. but iscanceled work for me.

Comment: I dont know why is not working earlier but what I want .. done @StinePike

Comment: @user2078315 I hope u have removed your downvote :(.. and i am curious.. what was the issue? ..

Comment: I did not give the downvate ... I appreciate that you helped me to sort out this problem and thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

You are re-initializing the task, instead make reference for the task and stop that task as follows:

```
            public class Activity1 extends Activity {

              CountDownTask countDownTask = new CountDownTask();

         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

countDownTask.execute();
             }

        @Override
          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
         return true;
            } 
          @Override
         public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
         countDownTask.cancel(true);
           }
```

Comment: I do not use the constructor in the class , so I think what u edit . it's not effect anything .. if u have another one answer or solution . let me know